# My Associative array is multi dimensional, and i can't figure out why. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative

Hi all. I'm currently in the middle of developing a login class that handles the user login. I get my array list back from the DB by creating it as an object with the following code:

```
 $dBquery = new Selection();
 $dBquery->setUpSelection($sqlConstructor);
 $sqllogin = $dBquery->sQLResults();
 print_r($sqllogin);
```

and from the `print_r`, this is what's returning:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [uSID] => 1
        [1] => 0
        [level] => 0
        [2] => a
        [Username] => > a
        [3] => a
        [password] => a
        [4] => a
        [email] => a
        [5] => 0
        [lockedID] => 0
    )
)
```

Now, from the looks of it, it's an array with in an array, which is a bit confusing since the code to create this array doesn't instigate that (I could be wrong, this is unfortunately where I need pointers). The code that sets up the array is:

```
private function selectAndQuery() {
        //Select query with AND
        $sql2 ="SELECT * FROM ".$this->table." WHERE ".$this->column."='".$this->where."' AND ".$this->andColumn."='".$this->sqlAnd."'  ";
        $a = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());      
        //get number of rows to determine if there are any results
        if (mysql_num_rows($a) < 1) {
                    //TO DO no results returned.
            $this->sQLResults();
        } else {
            //if there's a result store it into an array.
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
            $this->sqlResultsArray[] = $row; 
            }           
            $this->sQLResults();
        }
    }
```

So my question to you guys is, what's causing the array to go dimensional and what can I do to stop it? I know I could just pull the information from the multi-dimensional array but I was trying to keep things as simple as possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: `->sQLResults()` is oddly named, but sounds like it returns multiple possible results at all time (= a list of result rows). Note that you are not using the `->selectAndQuery` wrapper in your first code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->sqlResultsArray[] = $row; //This is causing you to get multidimensional array
since  mysql_fetch_array returns an array.So if you are sure that you will get only one
row.you can use below given mehod instead
if(mysql_num_rows() = 1){$this->sqlResultsArray  = mysql_fetch_array($a);}
```

Comment: The OP's function isn't limited to single-row-result queries, this'd trash all but the LAST row of any query which SHOULD return multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks Tarun, my results aren't limited but this technique can be used and the conditions changed. Thanks alot :)

Comment: As @MarcB state, you must be aware that, if you try to retrieve multiple rows and it only return one row(with the where clause), the behaviour will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the mysql_fetch function_array() function, which returns the row of data as an array. You then insert this array into your results array, so... yeah... multidimensional because you're fetching/building it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
    $this->sqlResultsArray[] = $row;
```

$row is an array.  You are adding this to the sqlResultsArray.

Answer (score 0):

Your selection is simply returning an array of all rows matching the query parameters, so at index 0 you'd have the first row, at index 1 the second row, and so on.

If you know that there will be at most one result, you could do this:

```
$sqllogin = $dBquery->sQLResults();
$sqllogin = $sqllogin[0];
```